# Function Scopes Understanding Unclear

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 1;
function b() {
    a = 10;
    return;
    function a() {}
}
b();
alert(a);
```

How is the output of 1 displayed for a? What does the

```
return;
function a() {}
```

within the function body perform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code is misleading and in a style that makes people think execution order matters. The standard JavaScript engine these days will take that and reformat prior to running it to:

```
var a = 1,
b = function() {
    var a = function() {};
    a = 10;
    return;
};
b();
alert(a);
```

Now you can understand what is actually happening. "a" is declared again inside the function "b" so there is actually two "a" variables now. One is "window.a" and the other one is "b var a" but NOT "b.a" because its not accessible outside of the closure or function.

In other words, you get what you code for.

Please make your code readable and don't confuse the point.

Comment: So I suppose the main point of the was you should write your code as if its already been parsed first. It will lead to greater readability. Douglas Crockford is the one to learn from.

Comment: @emeraldcode.com I personally agree, but there are people who like to break down code so that you can see and read the "essence" of the function at the top, with all the sub-parts coming afterwards. That style is what JavaScript (I *think*) is trying to facilitate. Personally I learned to code in Pascal back in the day, and you had to do things in exactly the opposite way :-)

Comment: @pointy -> This is a good learning tool for sure so its good he put the code up there. There is also the camp of just doing it Douglas Crockford style and all is good. I tend to just want the code to work and be readable as the main thing. Peace.

Comment: I too learned to code in Pascal, but I seem to have adopted a slightly mixed style as far as declaring things first versus declaring things later. Within a function I prefer to first declare variables, then declare any local functions, then the main body of the function. I think this works for me because it makes it obvious that the local functions can access those local variables. But if I have a "main" function or main piece of global code I like to put it before the rest of the functions but after any global variable declarations (though I try to minimise use of global variables).

Answer (score 6):

You declare a symbol "a" in the function with its last line. That's the "a" affected by the assignment statement.

Function declaration statements are hoisted up to the top of the function and are interpreted first. Thus, the assignment statement effectively happens *after* you've declared a function (local to the "b" function) named "a".  The assignment, therefore affects *that* symbol, not the global "a".

Remember that variables aren't typed, so the fact that you've bound a name to a function doesn't prevent it from being assigned a numeric value later.

Comment: Wow.  That is a great example of the lovely flexibility of javascript and the trouble it can get you into if you aren't careful about how you write it.

Comment: Yes!  The apparent simplicitly of JavaScript is what makes it complicated :-)

Comment: Sorry, Pointy, you made the same answer as me. I did not notice your answer but I will keep mine for clarity. +1 to you sir.